# where is it recommended to install WCF web services?

Tags: installation, wcf

I know you can install it anywhere physically and point the IIS applcation to the service.  What I can't find out is where it is most common to install the service itself.  Is it Program Files, InetPub, different location, or anywhere you want it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really doesn't matter, quite honestly.

If you're self-hosting, then you just install those WCF services wherever you install your app - any directory will be fine (typically under `c:\program files\(yourcompany)\(yourproduct)` or something).

When hosting in IIS: I would probably put them into e.g. a `Services` subdirectory under your app, if they're part of an app that contains other parts (e.g. ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF etc.), and create a virtual directory on that directory on disk.